# Download values of list from json file

Tags: c#, json.net

I have simple class

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<string> ParentsNames { get; set; }
}
```

And a json file

```json
[
  {
    "Name": "Frank",
    "Surname": "Wilson",
    "Age": "52",
    "Login": "fwillock",
    "Password": "willock123",
    "ParentsNames": [
      "Charles",
      "Sarah"
    ]
  },
  { 
    "Name": "Karen",
    "Surname": "Davies",
    "Age": "35",
    "Login": "kdavies",
    "Password": "davies123",
    "ParentsNames": [
      "Jason",
      "Angela"
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to get in console all names or surnames, existing in Person list. I tried to use something like this:

```cs
var JsonDeserialize = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
List<Person> result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Person>>(JsonDeserialize);
Console.WriteLine(result.Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
```

But i don't have any idea to use it in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list of names

```
var names= result.Select(i=> new {Name=i.Name, Surname=i.Surname}).ToList();
```

to print

```
foreach (var n in result) Console.WriteLine ( $"{n.Name} {n.Surname}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise how you display information in a class one option is to override `ToString()` for your `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    ...
    // customize however you like
    public override string ToString() => $"{Name} {Surname}";
}
```

Then to display in a single line, you could use [`string.Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Or if you want each person on a new line:

```
result.ForEach(person => Console.WriteLine(person));
// which can be shortened to
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```